# SQL Statement(s)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

If I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id int,
    num int,
    question varchar(50),
    qversion int );

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, 1, 'Question 1 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2, 1, 'Question 1 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3, 2, 'Question 2 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(4, 2, 'Question 2 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(5, 2, 'Question 2 v3', 3);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(6, 3, 'Question 3 v1', 1);

SELECT *
FROM #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

And I would like to get a table to display the three questions in their lastest version?  This is in SQL Server 2005

Comment: +1 for table create and insert statements. It appear though, if I understand the question correctly, that all the rows in the given test data should be returned. I would suggest including rows that would be excluded by the correct query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id int,
    num int,
    question varchar(50),
    qversion int );

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, 1, 'Question 1 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2, 1, 'Question 1 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3, 2, 'Question 2 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(4, 2, 'Question 2 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(5, 2, 'Question 2 v3', 3);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(6, 3, 'Question 3 v1', 1);

WITH latest AS (
   SELECT num, MAX(qversion) AS qversion
   FROM #temp
   GROUP BY num
)
SELECT #temp.*
FROM #temp
INNER JOIN latest
    ON latest.num = #temp.num
    AND latest.qversion = #temp.qversion;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: This is it, but there is an extra ')' in the sub query and the num needs to be in a group by.  (can't edit)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.num, t1.question, t1.qversion
FROM #temp t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp t2
  ON (t1.num = t2.num AND t1.qversion < t2.qversion)
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.num, t1.question, t1.qversion
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using SQL Server 2005, so it's worth at least exploring the [`over`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause:

```
select
    *
from
    (select *, max(qversion) over (partition by num) as maxVersion from #temp) s
where
    s.qversion = s.maxVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to get a table to display the three latest versions of each question*.

1. I *assume* that that qversion is increasing with time. If this assumption is backwards, remove the `desc` keyword from the answer.
2. The table definition does not have an explicit not null constraint on qversion. I *assume* that a null qversion should be excluded. (Note: Depending on settings, lack of an explicit null/not null in the declaration may result in a not null constraint.) If the table does have a not null contraint, than the text `where qversion is not null` should be removed. If qversion can be null, and nulls need to be included in the result set, then additional changes will need to be made.

---

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    id int,
    num int,
    question varchar(50),
    qversion int );

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(1, 1, 'Question 1 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(2, 1, 'Question 1 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(3, 2, 'Question 2 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(4, 2, 'Question 2 v2', 2);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(5, 2, 'Question 2 v3', 3);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(7, 2, 'Question 2 v4', 4); 
-- ^^ Added so at least one row would be excluded.
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(6, 3, 'Question 3 v1', 1);
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(8, 4, 'Question 4 v?', null);

select id, num, question, qversion
from (select *, 
        row_number() over (partition by num order by qversion desc) as RN
    from #temp
    where qversion is not null) T
where RN <= 3
```